# Touchpad is glitchy on Ubuntu 14.04 LTE

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

So, as the question states, my touchpad on my Acer AspireOne D255 is very glitchy with Ubuntu 14.04 LTE. For example, I will try to use the touchpad and my cursor will often move in the opposite direction my finger is moving, and then it will jump all over the screen. I know this isn't a hardware problem because my touchpad works with my partitions of Kali Linux, Windows 7 & Windows 8. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/384797/mousepad-is-jittery-and-inaccurate

Comment: @Sparhawk xinput doesn't even show that my touchpad is there.

Comment: I'm not really knowledgeable about this area, so I can't help you further, but it seems surprising (and perhaps informative) if `xinput` can't find it.

Comment: @Sparhawk I would guess the driver is missing but I've checked in the Ubuntu software system and I have the Synaptics touchpad driver installed. What would be helpful is if I could actually comment on that post you referred to.

Comment: Yes, the reputation system is very frustrating at the early stages (have an upvote to help). However, hopefully someone can help you on this question instead.